# What's the opposite to a chilli pepper's 'heat'?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

You describe chilli peppers as being *hot* despite them not being physically warm.
How would you describe a chilli pepper that is *not-hot*.

> The chilli peppers I have grown have all been very *[not-hot]*

What word would fit here?

Comment: ***mild*** (neutral), ***bland*** (negative), or some synonym from that constellation

Comment: Low on the scoville scale?

Comment: I think that peppers that aren't hot are often called sweet peppers.

Comment: We have Central America (Mexico?) to thank for the ubiquity of the hot chilli pepper (capsicum) here in Southeast Asia. The Portuguese brought them to Siam in late 15th century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I've answered my own question in the interests of closing the question. Thanks to Dan Bron for the ideas.</sup>

> #### Mild
>
> 4 . not sharp, pungent, or strong:
>   *a mild flavour.*
>
> 8 . moderate in intensity, degree, or character:
>   *mild regret.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mild))

A *mild* chllli is exactly what I was think of; it does not imply that its mildness (*not-hotness*) is a bad thing.

If you do want a word that considers the chilli's taste bad, **bland** is your word:

> #### Bland
>
> 4. not highly flavored; mild; tasteless:
>      *a bland sauce.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bland))

Comment: *Mild* is what is used to describe, for example, *chile ancho* (big, red, dried, wrinkled).  *Bland* is what is used to describe the dish made with a small amount of mild *chile*.